# Why is $\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin^2nx\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos^2nx\,\mathrm{d}x=\pi$?

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

Why is
$$
  \int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin^2nx\;\mathrm{d}x
  =
  \int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos^2nx\;\mathrm{d}x
  =\pi\,?
$$

I'm trying to understand a proof about Fourier series, and in my maths textbook, they do not explain how to solve this integral. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Their sum is $2\pi$ and they're the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$\sin^2(nx)=\frac 12 -\frac 12 \cos(2nx)\\\\
$$

and

$$\cos^2(nx)=\frac12 +\frac12 \cos(2nx)$$

In addition, for $n\ge 1$,

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(2nx)\,dx=0$$

Thus, we see immediately that

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2(nx)\,dx =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^2(nx)\,dx=\pi$$

Comment: Why the down vote??

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thank you!  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: This solid answer is perfect to me. I'm going to upvote it.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thank you!  Much appreciative.

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

As $\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1=1-2\sin^2A$

express $(\sin nx)^2,(\cos nx)^2$ in terms of $\cos(2nx)$

Now $\int\cos(mx)dx=\dfrac{\sin mx}m+K$

also $\sin(r\pi)=0$ for any integer $r$

Comment: Lab, why on earth did we receive down votes? Incredulous.

Comment: Correct answer. (+1).

Comment: @Dr.MV, I'm fade up with it. Nowadays, I just ignore them unless the error is pinpointed

Comment: Lab, I know.  It is that "hit-and-run" mentality that is hard to explain.

Comment: Any way +1 for your solid hints.

Answer (score 5):

First note that  $\sin^2(nx) + \cos^2(nx) = 1$ for all $x$. Thus $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi (\sin^2(nx) + \cos^2(nx)) dx = 2\pi.$$

Now we wish to show that each integral contributed the same amount to this. At the moment we know that the average of the two integrals is $\pi$.

It is important to remember that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are simply shifted copies of one another. Moreover, the period of $\sin(nx)$ is the same as that of $\cos(nx)$, and the period is $2\pi/n$. Since $n$ is an integer, each of $\sin^2(nx)$ and $\cos^2(nx)$ go through $n$ complete periods for $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ over the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. Thus, $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin^2(nx) dx = \int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos^2(nx) dx$$ and they are both equal to $\pi$ by this first equation.

Comment: I've seen this argument before but I'm still struggling to grasp it.

Comment: Essentially, $\sin^2$ and $\cos^2$ are roughtly the same function, just shifted a bit. And when you try to look at the area under their curves, you will find that for each period, they have the same area. Then you hope that your integral bounds happen to surround the same number of periods for both functions. If it does, then you win.

Comment: A non-example might help. Consider $$\int_{-\pi/8}^{\pi/8} \sin^2(x) dx \neq \int_{-\pi/8}^{\pi/8} \cos^2(x) dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sin^2(nx) = 1 - \cos^2(nx)$, so you can think of $\sin^2(nx)$ and $\cos^2(nx)$ as "upside-down" images of each other. Because $\cos^2(nx)$ is a phase shift of $\sin^2(nx)$, the "teeth" of the two curves interlock when $\cos^2(nx)$ is pictured upside-down (this is very loose, but you've seen lots of more technical explanations by now). Over the interval from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, both $\cos^2(nx)$ and $\sin^2(nx)$ go through the same number of cycles. So each should take up half of the $2\pi$ by $1$ rectangle, which has area $2\pi$. So each curve encloses an area of $\pi$.